# Check for string value in javascript

Tags: javascript

In JS we have two ways to check whether a given value is string or not:

```
function isString1(value) {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}


function isString2(value) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object String]";
}
```

which is efficient implementation and why?

Thanks!

Comment: If by better you more more elegant, definitely the first one.

Comment: I would use `if (typeof myVar == 'string' || myVar instanceof String)`

Comment: The first one is "better"... It uses fewer bytes... :)

Comment: @j08691 by better I mean more robust, memory and time efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you want to consider strings created using the `String` constructor, such as

```
new String("hello");
```

The first method will return `true` for pure strings and `false` for constructed strings:

```
typeof "hello" === "string" // true
typeof new String("hello") === "string" // false
```

whereas the second method will return `true` in both cases:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call("hello") === "[object String]" // true
Object.prototype.toString.call(new String("hello")) === "[object String]" // true
```

It is not common to use constructed strings, so for most practical purposes you will be fine using the simpler approach.

---

It is also worth noting that the behavior of the second approach can change if somebody modifies `Object.prototype.toString` (which, by the way, is an evil thing to do). If somebody does this, for example:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){ return "This is evil"; }
```

then

```
Object.prototype.toString.call("hello") === "This is evil"
```

The `typeof` operator is baked into the syntax and is not susceptible to this possibility.

Comment: that's why Lo-dash uses both ways! https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L2899

Comment: @peter well explained :)